# Reminder Pop up using php,jquery

Tags: php, jquery, performance

Show reminder pop-up for one customer based on the follow-up time reached for customers.

**Scenario**

I have 10 customers, i have set follow-up date and time for those customers between 10 am to 5 pm on today. If any customer's follow up date and time is reached that time will show pop-up with their details.

**Performance Issue**

Normally, This event will trigger, when the date and time is reached that time only trigger, So every second we should check the server time with corresponding tables. So If we check this kind of matching data in DB, definitely we should face performance/Lock issue.

How can be this done with efficiency using php, jquery or  any other tools??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same logic you can apply with a small modification.

Take the server time from the server and at the same time take all user ids and their follow-up date and time who all having the follow-up date and time in the same day (or all if there are no more no of users) and store it in client side (Cookie or local storage).

So every time you can check the date time(Take server time stored in client side cookie as reference) in the client side itself and if there is any match occurs only you7 need to make a call to the server side in order to take the corresponding details.